# Fourier coefficient to power

Tags: fourier-transform, audio

When doing a FT on a 4kHz and on a 8kHz signal
(both 0dB amplitude), the Audition spectrum view shows 0dB for both
freqencies as expected.

But the calculated fourier coefficients for both frequencies
are different: 1354 (for 4kHz) and 2043 (for 8kHz).

How is the connection/ formula between fourier coeffient
and volume (power)?

(I know this is a kind of very basic question,
but I haven't found something that explains that to me).

Comment: How exactly did you calculate the "Fourier" coefficients?

Comment: With a FFT alg I've taken from here (https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C.2B.2B), 2nd version

Comment: In other words: Are my values for the coeff. (for 4kHz and for 8kHz, both with 0dB) correct? If no: My using of the FFT must be wrong. If yes: How do I come from the coeff. for each frequency to its power?

Comment: What's your sample rate and what's your FFT length? Do you apply any window ?

Comment: Sample rate is 44100 Hz, FFT window size is 4096 samples.

Comment: I shift the window (of 4096 samples) along the complete audio. For every window I compute the FFT and it always returns 1 peak for the fourier coeff. at the specific frequency (4k or 8k). I don't understand how these coeff. correlate to the power or dB of the frequency. I think it should be 0 dB, as the amplitude of the samples is, and Audition shows it in the spectrogram... What is the formula from fourier coeff. to dB? What does coeff. 1354 at 4kHz mean with respect to the volume, dB? It seems to be the maximum possible coeff. for 4kHz, and 2043 for 8kHz, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) represents a time signal as a sum of complex exponentials. A sine wave consists of two complex exponentials, i.e. $\cos(\omega t) = \tfrac12 (e^{-j\omega t} + e^{+j\omega t})$.

For a single complex exponential the peak magnitude will be $N$, where $N$ is the length of the FFT. That is simply a function of the standard mathematical definition of the Discrete Fourier Transform.

For a single sine wave we would expect two peaks at $-\omega$ and $+\omega$ with a  magnitude of $\tfrac{N}2$.

> But the calculated fourier coefficients for both frequencies are different: 1354 (for 4kHz) and 2043 (for 8kHz).

That's spectral leakage. The DFT uses a discrete set of frequencies. If your sample rate would be 40 kHz  and your FFT length 4000, these frequencies would be 0Hz, 10Hz, 20Hz, ...

If the frequency of your sine wave matches one of these "bin" frequencies exactly, you will get a single peak of $\tfrac{N}2$. If not, the energy of the sine wave is "smeared out" over all FFT bins with the most energy in the bins closest to the sine wave frequency.

In your case 8kHz is very close to a bin frequency and hence you get almost 2048 as expected. 4kHz, however falls almost in the middle between two bin frequencies so the energy is more smeared out. The peak is 1353 but the bin right next to it has still 1254, the two neighboring bins get most of the energy.

Comment: Thank you very much (again!) for your help! It's much too long ago that I learned the basic knowledge, and by that I was on a completely wrong track. At least it suffices to understand your kind explanation. :-)