# FFT of a Time series data

Tags: python, dft, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


def DFT(x):
    """
    Function to calculate the 
    discrete Fourier Transform 
    of a 1D real-valued signal x
    """

    N = len(x)
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = n.reshape((N, 1))
    e = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    
    X = np.dot(e, x)
    
    return X


t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
S_t = np.sin(1*t)

S_w = DFT(S_t)
print(np.real(S_w))
```

> Since, there exist only one harmonic (here, fundamental frequency at
> w=1) so S_w must posses only non-zero value at w = 1 and all other
> entries shall be 0. Right ? But, as I am running the code I am not
> getting it. Could anyone suggest me what shall be reformed in the
> code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `so S_w must posses only non-zero value at w = 1 and all other entries shall be 0. Right?` Wrong. This is only the case if your sine wave an integer number or periods per FFT

Comment: @Hilmar, I request if you could kindly elaborate a little more.

Comment: It's  about "spectral leakage", see for example my recent answer here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76980/fourier-coefficient-to-power/76988#76988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `np.linspace(0, 100, 1000, endpoint=False)` to yield full integer periods
2. `np.sin(2*np.pi * 1 * t)`
3. `np.imag` for `np.sin` and `np.real` for `np.cos`

```
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000, 0)
S_t = np.sin(2*np.pi*1*t)
S_w = DFT(S_t)
print(np.imag(S_w[98:102]))
```

```
[-1.27203803e-12  2.30915287e-12 -5.00000000e+02  1.30867539e-12]
```

Checking against standard implementation and plotting:

```
assert np.allclose(S_w, np.fft.fft(S_t))
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(S_w.real)
plt.plot(S_w.imag)
```

[image]

Comment: np.linspace(0, 100, 1000, endpoint=False) ; If I put endpoint = True, what changes may occur? I mean How does it differs from np.linspace(0, 100, 1000) ?

Comment: One more thing, If I perform DFT of a Time-Series data, we expect to get w(angular frequency) data in angular frequency space, But, I am looking for frequency(f = w/2*pi) space data, will both be equal ?

Comment: @SubhadipSaha 1) try `linspace(0, 1, 10, False)` vs `linspace(0, 1, 10, True)`; `False` makes it so that `fs` in `linspace(0, 1, fs)` is the actual sampling rate, check `1 / (t[1] - t[0])` with `t=linspace` -- 2) conversion between linear and angular is `2*pi` as you've shown, so to get "angular DFT" just multiply each bin by `2*pi` - in your example it's `100*2*pi = 628 rad/s`